# How to get country name by ip address using google api

Tags: php, google-api

I already have the google api key and want to know if it is possible to get country name of user(not share location) without any account from google Api

i think it is possible from user ip address but don't know how

Comment: hint: try google's docs

Comment: i tried but did't get any thing

Comment: thats not possible.

Comment: you can always use the geoplugin.net api. Its free and gives you detailed location

Comment: how google acquire location without my location sharing (after searching you will see in fotter)

Answer (score 0):

API key is for public data.   So the user in question would need to have set it to public.

The Google+ api is a public api and does allow for [search of people](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/search) so if the user in question has a google+ account and they have set their location to public you might be able to see it.

That is the only api i know of that contains public information about a user.

**Private data option**

If this user is within your Google contacts for example or collected to you then you can go though the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) however this is also going to require that you have filled out the data for them.

**Geo Location IP option**

There are several APIs that are not related to google which support geo location lookup of ip addresses   http://www.hostip.info/use.html  Note: they can be slow

Comment: i want information of user surfing website without any login detail

Comment: Just do a geo lookup on the ip address then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,
No need for Google Api

Check here : https://freegeoip.net

```
$geo_location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
print_r($geo_location);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-name-by-name.php

kindly try this above referencee manual will get solution.